# setInterval, .delay? Timing and fading in of hidden divs

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've set a button so when you click it, it displays the 4 'hidden' divs. I would really like the divs to appear slower, one by one but I can't get it to work.. I'll grateful for any help. Thanks.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("home");

  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";

  } else {

    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url(images/image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

button {
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Home</button>

<div id="home" style="display: none">

  <div class="home1">
    <h2>Kitchen</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="home2">
    <h2>Lounge</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="home3">
    <h2>Dining Room</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="home4">
    <h2>Contact us</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mention you can't get it to work -- can you please share what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

- Use the `data-*` attribute to store the desired selector.
- Use JavaScript to assign dynamically the CSS `transition` timings
- Use JS to `classList` toggle a `is-active` class
- use CSS to handle the styles for your `.section` elements
- Don't use `display: none / block` or the inner elements won't *transition* correctly

```js
function togglePage() { // "myFunction" means nothing.

  const EL_page = document.querySelector(this.dataset.togglePage);
  const ELS_section = EL_page.querySelectorAll(".section");
  const is_active = EL_page.classList.contains("is-active");
  const duration = is_active ? 0 : 1000;
  const delay = is_active ? 0 : 300;
  ELS_section.forEach((el, i) => el.style.transition = `opacity ${duration}ms ${delay * i}ms`);
  EL_page.classList.toggle("is-active");

}

document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle-page]").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", togglePage);
});
```

```css
/* DEFAULT STATES */
.page {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.page .section {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* ACTIVE STATES handled by JS */
.page.is-active { 
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.page.is-active .section {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle-page="#home">Home</button>

<div id="home" class="page">
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Kitchen</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Lounge</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Dining Room</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Contact us</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! Works like a dream.. I had tried transition, delay and fadeIn but probably as above I was using the display: none/block function it wasn't working.